# Rotation of Axis

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, language-agnostic

I am using the [rotation of axis formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes) as follows:

[image]

Assuming θ is 30 degrees so in order to go back to un-rotated state I am simply using (360-30) for α (all in radians). However, I am not getting back to 0 degrees. I have added the code in python for verification, so everything seems fine (adding 90 degrees or <sup>π</sup>/<sub>2</sub> for α) gives me correct offset however, adding offset to go back to "un-rotated" state is an issue.

What could be the problem?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import numpy.random as rnd


angle=2 * np.pi * rnd.random(size=1)
print("angle",np.degrees(angle))
x_circle90 = np.cos(np.pi / 2)
y_circle90 = np.sin(np.pi / 2)
x_90 = (x_circle90 * (40 * 0.5))
y_90 = (y_circle90 * (50 * 0.5))
xx90 = x_90 * np.cos(angle) - y_90 * np.sin(angle) + 108
yy90 = x_90 * np.sin(angle) + y_90 * np.cos(angle) + 60


x_circle0 = np.cos(0)
y_circle0 = np.sin(0)
x_0 = (x_circle0 * (40 * 0.5))
y_0 = (y_circle0 * (50 * 0.5))
xx0 = x_0 * np.cos(angle) - y_0 * np.sin(angle) + 108
yy0 = x_0 * np.sin(angle) + y_0 * np.cos(angle) + 60

negation=(2*np.pi-angle)
x_circlen = np.cos(negation)
y_circlen = np.sin(negation)
x_n = (x_circlen * (40 * 0.5))
y_n = (y_circlen * (50 * 0.5))
xxn = x_n * np.cos(angle) - y_n * np.sin(angle) + 108
yyn = x_n * np.sin(angle) + y_n * np.cos(angle) + 60


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_patch(
    Ellipse(xy=[108,60],
            width=40,
            height=50,
            angle=np.degrees(angle),
            fill=False, color='k', linewidth=1))

ax.plot(xx0, yy0, 'rp', color='blue', markersize=2)
ax.plot(xx90, yy90, 'rp', color='green', markersize=2)
ax.plot(xxn, yyn, 'rp', color='black', markersize=2)
ax.plot(108,60,'rp', color='red', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=200)
ax.set_ylim(0, 200)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
plt.pause()
plt.close
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is you have known ellipse (`x0,y0,rx,ry`) rotated by `a0` and want to obtain the point on ellipse that will create exact angle `ma` between ellipse center and axis going through it and parallel to x.

1. you got the minus sign wrong it should be before one of the `sin(a)` ...
2. this is rotation of XY plane or around `z` axis if you want!!!
3. parametric angle `b` is nonlinear so simple substraction will not work

The rotation formula itself is:

```
x' =  x*cos(a) - y*sin(a)
y' =  x*sin(a) + y*cos(a)
```

or:

```
x' =  x*cos(a) + y*sin(a)
y' = -x*sin(a) + y*cos(a)
```

for the reverse direction ... Now parametric ellipse is:

```
x = rx*cos(b)
y = ry*sin(b)
```

So when put together (second rotation formula):

```
x' =  rx*cos(b)*cos(a) + ry*sin(b)*sin(a)
y' = -rx*cos(b)*sin(a) + ry*sin(b)*cos(a)
```

Now that we have formula that can get us point from parametric angle we want to compute point from real angle. That can be done in more ways. I choosed to:

1. compute direction vector with real angle `ma`
2. un-rotate it by `a0`
3. rescale it so ellipse would become circle
   simply by multiplying `x` or `y` (just one) by ratio `ry/rx` or `rx/ry`
4. rotate by `a0`
5. using atan2 to obtain parametric angle

Here C++/VCL example:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const double pi2=6.283185307179586476925286766559;
const double deg=6.283185307179586476925286766559/360.0;
double x0=125,y0=75,rx=100,ry=50.0,a0=15.0*deg; // ellipse center,radiuses,rotation
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ellipse_draw(TCanvas *can) // render ellipse
    {
    int e;
    double b=0.0,db=0.01*pi2,x,y;
    x =  rx*cos(b)*cos(a0) + ry*sin(b)*sin(a0) +x0;
    y = -rx*cos(b)*sin(a0) + ry*sin(b)*cos(a0) +y0;
    can->MoveTo(x,y);
    for (e=1;e;b+=db)
        {
        if (b>=pi2) { b=pi2; e=0; }
        x =  rx*cos(b)*cos(a0) + ry*sin(b)*sin(a0) +x0;
        y = -rx*cos(b)*sin(a0) + ry*sin(b)*cos(a0) +y0;
        can->LineTo(x,y);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ellipse_getpnt(double &mx,double &my,double ma) // (mx,my) = point at global angle ma from (x0,y0)
    {
    int e;
    double b,x,y;
    // direction vector with global angle ma in ellipse local coordinates
    b=ma+a0;
    x =cos(b);
    y =sin(b);
    // rescale to circle
    y*=rx/ry;
    // convert (x,y) to unrotated coordinates
    mx =  x*cos(a0) + y*sin(a0);
    my = -x*sin(a0) + y*cos(a0);

    // b = atan2(my,mx)
    e=1;
    if (fabs(mx)<1e-3){ e=0; b=+90.0*deg; if (my<0) b= -90.0*deg; }
    if (fabs(my)<1e-3){ e=0; b=+ 0.0*deg; if (mx<0) b=+180.0*deg; }
    if (fabs(mx)+fabs(my)<1e-3){ e=0;  ma=0.0*deg; }
    if (e) b=atan2(my,mx);

    b+=a0;

    // point on ellipse with new angle
    mx =  rx*cos(b)*cos(a0) + ry*sin(b)*sin(a0) +x0;
    my = -rx*cos(b)*sin(a0) + ry*sin(b)*cos(a0) +y0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first function just renders the ellipse by lines (just so you can match your rendering and coordinate system). The second one is the computation you need. It computes `mx,my` point coordinates corresponding to real angle `ma`.

Here preview:

[image: preview]

Blue is ellipse, gray is direction to real angle (I used mouse position) and Aqua is line between ellipse center and computed point for real angle. As you can see it overlaps exactly so it works. It works along the whole circumference.

For simplicity I used the `atan2` function which is common but at least on mine environment I had to handle some edge cases ...

Comment: I didn't quite catch that, I am using the normal formula that is shown in the wikipedia equations. So by saying go to "un-rotated" state in the "transformed coordinates", I mean to go back to "0 degrees" from the perspective of untransformed coordinates with x-axis as horizontal and y-axis as vertical. So to do so I just have to plug in the difference in angle into $\alpha$ so the difference is 360-(rotation), so if the coordinates are rotated 30 degrees so the difference in angle to plug into equation would be 330 for $\alpha$ and 30 for $\theta$ to get (x',y') at 0 degrees in rotated coord.

Comment: I am using polar coordinates because the application I am using has the coordinates already tilted to $\theta$ so I have to compute angles in unrotated/untransformed coordinates that correspond to rotated coordinates, I thought it should be easy as say everything is shifted/rotated by $\theta$ so I can minus the $\theta$ first and then add the angle that corresponds to angle in unrotated coordinates and it will reflect corresponding values of (x,y) of the rotated ellipse.

Comment: @metron rotation in polar coordinates is just angle change no `sin,cos` is involved ... conversion from polar to cartesian has just single sin and cos without nay minus sign ... you mentioned ellipse??? maybe you should edit your question and add all the `relevant details` on what exactly you are trying to do... what you have as input and what output you want  and what is the problem you are stuck with. Because if I put all the stuff from your question and your comments together it does not make any sense to me. Maybe sketch/image would be better if you do not know how to express it by words.

Comment: alright, good suggestion. My bad, The equation plots an ellipse. so (x',y') correspond to point on the edge of the ellipse in the rotated coordinates. I will plot it and mark on it because geometry problems are bit hard to express in words. I am not doing polar coordinates, the stuff I wrote is in cartesian coordinates, however The cartesian coordinates are rotated from the origin to say $\theta$ = 30 degrees. Now in the new coordinate a 0 degree will correspond to 30 degree in untransformed coordinates. Till here I think it clear.

Comment: Now, I want to know what will be the x' and y' , the point on the edge of the ellipse if I have angle in untransformed coordinates. So say angle is say 5 degrees in un transformed coordinates what is the corresponding value of the point at the edge of the ellipse that is rotated/transfromed 30 degrees. So I have the formula as above that only gives me x' y' if the $\alpha$ value given is relative to the new rotated coordinates which are rotated by 30 degrees. how ever to give relative alpha value $\alpha$ what I am doing is first untransfroming it $360 -30$ and adding 5 degrees to it.

Comment: In your edited formula, shall I add a=30 degrees to reflect the coordinates transformed by 30 and to reflect the value of the point on the transformed ellipse relative to "untransformed coordinates" shall I add b = 5 ?

Comment: @metron `a` is the rotation of whole ellipse, `b` is the angle along unrotated elipse (selecting which point you want to compute where `b=0` is major semiaxis), `rx,ry` are the semi axises... Beware for ellipse `b` is not actual angle !!!

Comment: @metron If you want `b` to be actual angle then the computation is much much more complicated ... as `b` is nonlinear (you know if you sample `b` by 10 deg the elliptic slices will not have 10 deg angle (some will  be bigger others smaller ...)

Comment: I thought b = 360 - transformed angle + actual angle. This is what I did in my code and not getting back to 0 degrees if I plug actual angle to be 0, in the figure I attached the black dot represents what I got by having b = 360 - transformed angle + 0, its offset from true 0. The blue dot represents the transformed angle which was initially at 0, and the green dot represents the 90 degree offset from the transformed angle which appears right.

Comment: @metron so You got rotated ellipse `rx,ry` with known angle of rotation `a` and  want to get point on ellipse that will be exactly at some angle measured from x axis of screen ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want . From the x axis of the screen. I couldn't have described it better.

Comment: @metron oki give me a second need to check it in C++ ... btw that is the complicated stuff I was mentioning before ... There are more options to do it like fitting, using implicit equation, rescaling to circle etc ...

Comment: @metron I added working C++ example (not using python but you should port the math easily).

Comment: Awesome! Accepted the answer. I shall implement and get back if there are any questions. From what I see is that now b is angle with respect to x-axis of the screen.